# Acumatica - How to invoke Create Receipt action on a Sales Order (Type RC) programatically

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to process return orders in Acumatica, for which I will have to create a Sales Order of type RC, invoke the Create Receipt Action on the sales order which creates a shipment of type Receipt and then invoke Confirm Shipment on the shipment. However in the list of Actions defined on the Sales Order, I do not find an action corresponding to Create Receipt. Can anyone guide me on how to invoke the Create Receipt action programatically as we do through the screen?

For e.g. this is how I invoke Confirm Shipment on a shipment and looking for something similar to Create Receipt:

```
var adapter = new PXAdapter(graph.CurrentDocument);
adapter.Arguments.Add("actionID", SOShipmentEntryActionsAttribute.ConfirmShipment);
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(graph, delegate () 
{ 
    foreach (SOShipment soShipment in graph.action.Press(adapter)) ; 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution previously provided by Acumatica, I tried this method in few screens and it was working. In the following code try to change the graph to your *SOOrderEntry* and  Command to "Create Receipt"

```
docgraph.Document.Current = docgraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>("mYsHIPMENTnUMBER");
            docgraph.Cancel.Press();
            foreach (var action in (docgraph.action.GetState(null) as PXButtonState).Menus)
            {
                if (action.Command == "Confirm Shipment")
                {
                    PXAdapter adapter2 = new PXAdapter(new DummyView(docgraph, docgraph.Document.View.BqlSelect, new List<object> { docgraph.Document.Current }));
                    adapter2.Menu = action.Command;
                    docgraph.action.PressButton(adapter2);

                }
            }

 internal class DummyView : PXView
        {
            List<object> _Records;
            internal DummyView(PXGraph graph, BqlCommand command, List<object> records)
                : base(graph, true, command)
            {
                _Records = records;
            }
            public override List<object> Select(object[] currents, object[] parameters, object[] searches, string[] sortcolumns, bool[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, ref int startRow, int maximumRows, ref int totalRows)
            {
                return _Records;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've 1 more problem to sort before I can test this. I'm creating an Order- type RC programatically. I create instance of graph & fill in mandatory fields & other info for the return order. When I call Save.Press() action, error- Inserting  'Billing Address' record raised at least one error. When I create order thru screen, I just select customer- address is filled automatically. I even tried updating the address details but still same error. How to get necessary details filled automatically as when done thru screen? Or how to find what field is missing so I can populate data for that.

Comment: You might need to post your code. However, please make sure that you are updating the record back to cache after you set the fields that require commits. say, SOOrder.BaccountID = <Something>; Then graph.Document.Update(SOOrder); This will trigger events that are required to populate  other fields.

Comment: Thanks @Hybridzz, I was able to overcome that. When I invoke the Create Receipt action, I get PX.Data.PXDialogRequiredException. How do I provide the response OK to the dialog. I found this SetAnswer() method on the view but I need to pass the identifier of the dialog along with the WebDialogResult and I do not know how to get the webdialog identifier.

Comment: For the identifier of the dialog, it was enough to pass null.